# Exception in async method executing in UI-thread crashes application

Tags: wpf, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library, ui-thread

When I `await` on a method that throws an exception, try/catch do not save application from crashing.

There is a throwing method

```
void CurrentStep.Process(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

It is called from the UI thread by the means of `ICommand.Execute()`

```
ProcessCurrentStepCommand = AsyncCommandFactory.Create(async cancellationToken => 
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => CurrentStep.Process(cancellationToken));
    }
    catch {}

    CurrentStep = CurrentStep.NextStepViewModel;
});
```

`ProcessCurrentStepCommand` is bound to the button on UI. When I click the button, my application breaks.
I feel that there is a general problem with throwing an exception on UI thread, but at the same time I don't understand why catch block isn't saving me from exception.

I have found the only way that works for me now:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(
    action: () => CurrentStep.Process(cancellationToken),
    creationOptions: TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

But it looks ugly. If I forget in the future what I wanted to do with this code I might think that I need to clean it and get into trouble with some exception knocking out the whole application.

---

When in debug mode, everything behaves nicely.

1. Original break on the source of exception.
   [image]

> #### *Call stack*:
>
> **UI.exe**!UI.Steps.ViewModels.SvmConnectionViewModel.Process(System.Threading.CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   **UI.exe**!UI.MainViewModel..ctor.AnonymousMethod__1() Line 18
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() Line 2911
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() Line 2523
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object
>   obj) Line 2888
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 581
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 531
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) Line 2853
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Line 2792
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   Line 2729
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() Line 830
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>   Line 1171

2. Next break happens in **TaskAwaiter.cs** in method **ThrowForNonSuccess()**: `NotImplementedException occured: A first chance exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`.
   [image]

> #### *Call stack*:
>
> **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   task) Line 180
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   task) Line 170
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   Line 125
>   **UI.exe**!UI.MainViewModel..ctor(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 18
>   ***[Resuming Async Method]***
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(object
>   stateMachine) Line 1065
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 581
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 531
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
>   Line 1045
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.OutputAsyncCausalityEvents>.AnonymousMethod__0()
>   Line 973
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
>   Line 1085
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__0()
>   Line 301
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
>   Line 1085
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.GetActionLogDelegate.AnonymousMethod__3()
>   Line 470
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation..cctor.AnonymousMethod__6(object
>   state) Line 393
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate
>   callback, object args, int numArgs) Line 118  Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object
>   source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs,
>   System.Delegate catchHandler) Line 41 Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>   Line 583  Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object
>   state) Line 528   Unknown
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 581
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 531
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state) Line 520
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>   Line 441  Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() Line 2227  Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr
>   hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool
>   handled) Line 2480    Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
>   Line 345  Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object
>   o) Line 494   Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate
>   callback, object args, int numArgs) Line 111  Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object
>   source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs,
>   System.Delegate catchHandler) Line 41 Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority
>   priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object
>   args, int numArgs) Line 1447  Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Line
>   398   Unknown
>   ***[Native to Managed Transition]***
>   ***[Managed to Native Transition]***
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
>   frame) Line 2281  Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
>   frame) Line 369   Unknown
>   **WindowsBase.dll**!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() Line 328    Unknown
>   **PresentationFramework.dll**!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object
>   ignore) Line 2745
>   **PresentationFramework.dll**!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window
>   window) Line 1841
>   **PresentationFramework.dll**!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window
>   window) Line 261
>   **PresentationFramework.dll**!System.Windows.Application.Run() Line 222   UI.exe!UI.App.Main()
>   ***[Native to Managed Transition]***
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) Line
>   2031
>   **Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll**!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() Unknown
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object
>   state) Line 74
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 581
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 531
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state) Line 520
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() Line 111
>   ***[Async Call]***
>   **UI.exe**!UI.Commands.AsyncCommandFactory.Create(System.Threading.CancellationToken
>   token) Line 27
>   ***[Async Call]***
>   **UI.exe**!UI.NotifyTaskCompletion.WatchTaskAsync(System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   task) Line 66
>   ***[Async Call]***
>   **UI.exe**!UI.Commands.AsyncCommand.ExecuteAsync(object parameter) Line 55
>   ***[Async Call]***
>   **UI.exe**!UI.Commands.AsyncCommandBase.Execute(object parameter) Line 15

3. The next break with the same exception and almost the same as previous stack trace (the difference is only in the first of 4 last methods called).

> #### *Call stack*:
>
> **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   task) Line 180
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   task) Line 170
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   Line 125
>   **UI.exe**!UI.Commands.AsyncCommandFactory.Create(System.Threading.CancellationToken token) Line 27
>   ***[Resuming Async Method]***
>   ...

4. The next one is again differs only in the one method.

> #### *Call stack*:
>
> **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   task) Line 180
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   task) Line 170
>   **mscorlib.dll**!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   Line 125
>   **UI.exe**!UI.NotifyTaskCompletion.WatchTaskAsync(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) Line 66
>   ***[Resuming Async Method]***
>   ...

5. After previous break there are no more raised exceptions and Task.IsFaulted is set to true. Now UI successfully shows the exception message using this binding:

```xml
<Label Content="{Binding ProcessCurrentStepCommand.Execution.ErrorMessage}" Visibility="{Binding ProcessCurrentStepCommand.Execution.IsFaulted, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

---

## Final Edit.

To understand the context of the question and the accepted answer, you will need to look at these articles:

- [Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx)
- [Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn630647.aspx)

Comment: What is the exception being thrown? Do you have a stack trace for the thrown exception?

Comment: It behaves differently when I'm launching it in debug mode. I will edit my answer to include these stacktraces.

Comment: @Pixar: The `catch` block *is* catching it. It's just that the debugger is seeing it first and notifying you, that's all.

Comment: @Stephen: yes, I understand that. I have included all these stack traces to diagnose the problem.
And it's great that you've come to see my question, because I've used your article to create asynchronious commands :)
Now I can be more specific to your examples AsyncCommand1, AsyncCommand2, AsyncCommand3 and AsyncCommand4.
If you add `throw new Exception()` right at the begining of your method MyService.DownloadAndCountBytesAsync(), application will also crash when you press `Go` button.

Comment: @Pixar: Yes. Commands are conceptually like events, and if you throw an exception from any event handler (or command), it will be treated as a top-level application exception, with the default behavior of crashing. What is the behavior you expect?

Comment: @Stephen: I want the same thing that you wanted when you catched all exceptions in `NotifyTaskCompletion.WatchTaskAsync()` with  

try
    {
      await task;
    }
    catch
    {
    }

"This method violates a common coding guideline here: It has an empty general catch clause. In this case, though, that’s exactly what I want. I don’t want to propagate exceptions directly back to the main UI loop; **I want to capture any exceptions and set properties so that the error handling is done via data binding**".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don’t want to propagate exceptions directly back to the main UI loop; I want to capture any exceptions and set properties so that the error handling is done via data binding.

In that case, what you really need is a *synchronous* command that just *starts* the asynchronous operation, where the asynchronous operation is represented using `NotifyTaskCompletion` (or some similar type you write). Breaking apart the operation like this (into a synchronous "start" and asynchronous data binding) is easier than trying to do it all in one (which is also possible - it's just that the code isn't as short or reusable):

```
// Represents the execution of the current step.
NotifyTaskCompletion ProcessCurrentStepCommandExecution
{
  get { return _processCurrentStepCommandExecution; }
  set { _processCurrentStepCommandExecution = value; PropertyChanged(); }
}

...

var cancellationToken = ...; // Wherever you get this from.
ProcessCurrentStepCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
{
  ProcessCurrentStepCommandExecution = new NotifyTaskCompletion(async () =>
  {
    await Task.Run(() => CurrentStep.Process(cancellationToken));

    // I'm assuming here you only want to move to the next step if there are no errors.
    // Otherwise, this should be in a finally block.
    CurrentStep = CurrentStep.NextStepViewModel;
  });
});
```

**Edit:**

I believe you may be running into a bug in the example code for that article (there used to be updated code in the comments before MSDNMag decided to delete them all, and I'm working to get the code sample updated, a surprisingly long process). The bug occurs if the task completes synchronously (with exception or success); in that case, `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>.TaskCompleted` will be `null`.

To fix this, change the constructor for `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` from this:

```
{
    Task = task;
    if (!task.IsCompleted)
        TaskCompletion = WatchTaskAsync(task);
}
```

to this:

```
{
    Task = task;
    TaskCompletion = WatchTaskAsync(task);
}
```

Comment: 1. This sentence was from your [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx). Why haven't you used `await Task.Run(...)` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn630647.aspx)?
2. If I `throw new Exception()` in `Task.Run(...)`, it will still crush.
3. Maybe it would be better to see what changes would you do to the code from AsyncCommand[i] projects from the article [Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn630647.aspx)? :)

Comment: @Pixar: `Task.Run` is used to push CPU-bound work off the UI thread. I include it in this answer because it was in your code; it is not included in my article because I only do I/O-based operations there.

Comment: If we insert in the beginning of I/O-bound method `MyService.DownloadAndCountBytesAsync()` the command `throw new Exception()` right before `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), token).ConfigureAwait(false);`, the application AsyncCommand[i] will crash. It is difficult to imagine that Task.Delay may throw, but imagine that it is more complex method that might, for example, make a division by 0 before it's first `await`.

Comment: @Pixar: Whether it's before or after the `await` doesn't make a difference. A failing `AsyncCommand` task is treated the same as throwing an exception from a synchronous event handler. If you want to data bind to the exceptions, use `NotifyTaskCompletion`.

Comment: I am using it `Execution = new NotifyTaskCompletion<TResult>(_command(_cancelCommand.Token));`. That is the whole point of this question :)
In your [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn630647.aspx) you are also using `NotifyTaskCompletion` and it WILL crash if `Task.Delay` ever thows an exception.
How would you change your examples so that they are guarded against such a situation?

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience! :)
On one hand, I am happy to finally understand the cause of the problem, on the other hand, I feel bad for my debugging skills and I wonder would my question ever be helpful for anyone except me :)

Comment: @Pixar: Actually, thank you for your patience - since the bug was in my code, not yours! :)